# Inatalling Flash Player in Linux via a ssh session

Tags: linux, adobe, flash

I have download and extracted 64 bit install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz Adobe Flash Player via a ssh session (wget command). Now the package states that **"Copy the libflashplayer.so file to the plugins folder of your browser."**

It states that default it should be /usr/lib/firefox/plugins, but:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/firefox/plugins
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/firefox/plugins: No such file or directory
```

I would be an using a X Windows Client for same - so where should I copy **/opt/libflashplayer.so** shared library?

To give an insight I am installing [Weave](http://info.iweave.com/projects/weave/wiki/Setup_Flash_for_Linux) - the app would actually run on a browser on a client box expect that deployment is completely done in Linux box - so is it that I need to install **/opt/libflashplayer.so**

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the plugin directory might actually be at

```
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
```

However, I would maybe recommend installing it to the home plugins folder at

```
~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Reference: [Determining plugin directory on Linux](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Determining_plugin_directory_on_Linux)

Comment: /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins if you are on a 64 bit machine